# plotly 3D scatterplot in R z axis and isomorphis

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to set out a 3D Scatterplot with the R interface to plotly.
My plotly call is:

```
p.sagittale<-plot_ly(data=filter(temp,tipo=='Caucasici'), x = ~coordX.Sagg , y = ~ coordY.Sagg, z = ~coordZ.Sagg,text = ~punti) %>% 
add_markers(color=~cluster) %>% 
layout(title = paste('Caucasici','Dente',i,'Sagittale'), xaxis = myaxis.list, yaxis = myaxis.list, zaxis=myaxis.list)
```

where the myaxis.list is defined as before:

```
myaxis.list<- list(
    zeroline = TRUE,
    showline = TRUE,
    mirror = "ticks",
    gridcolor = toRGB("gray50"),
    gridwidth = 2,
    zerolinecolor = toRGB("blue"),
    zerolinewidth = 4,
    linecolor = toRGB("black"),
    linewidth = 6,
    autotick = FALSE,
    ticks = "outside",
    tick0 = 0,
    dtick = 0.25
  )
```

I have two issues:
1. I receive a warning:

> "Warning message: 'layout' objects don't have these attributes:
>   'zaxis' Valid attributes include: 'font', 'title', 'titlefont',
>   'autosize', 'width', 'height', 'margin', 'paper_bgcolor',
>   'plot_bgcolor', 'separators', 'hidesources', 'smith', 'showlegend',
>   'dragmode', 'hovermode', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'scene', 'geo', 'legend',
>   'annotations', 'shapes', 'images', 'updatemenus', 'ternary', 'mapbox',
>   'radialaxis', 'angularaxis', 'direction', 'orientation', 'barmode',
>   'bargap', 'mapType'".

So my first question is: how to set out the z axis esthetics?

2. I would like to have an isomorphic graph: same spacing between ticks, same scale on the x,y,z axis. How can I get this?

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: can you include a dataset to your post?

Comment: Yes, a dput image is here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7ct3xpfwwj555gh/AAAJc7u3aIxIBoN4dtvjKqora?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to wrap your axes in a [`scene`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene).

```
layout(scene = list(xaxis = myaxis.list,
                    yaxis = myaxis.list,
                    zaxis = myaxis.list),
       )
```

and specify the range (i.e. upper and lower bound) of your axes via [`range`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-range).

```
myaxis.list<- list( 
  autorange = FALSE,
  range = c(-5, 5)
  [...]
)
```

---

The complete code for the graph below

```
myaxis.list<- list( 
  zeroline = TRUE, 
  showline = TRUE, 
  mirror = "ticks", 
  gridcolor = toRGB("gray50"), 
  gridwidth = 2, 
  zerolinecolor = toRGB("blue"), 
  zerolinewidth = 4, 
  linecolor = toRGB("black"), 
  linewidth = 6, 
  autotick = FALSE, 
  ticks = "outside", 
  tick0 = 0, 
  dtick = 0.25,
  autorange = FALSE,
  range = c(-5, 5)
) 
p.sagittale<-plot_ly(data=filter(temp,tipo=='Caucasici'), x = ~coordX.Sagg , y = ~ coordY.Sagg, z = ~coordZ.Sagg,text = ~punti) %>%
add_markers(color=~cluster) %>%
layout(title = paste('Caucasici','Dente',"i",'Sagittale'), scene=list(xaxis = myaxis.list, yaxis = myaxis.list, zaxis=myaxis.list))
```

[image]